# When I deleted someone from family sharing will they lose their pictures?

Tags: icloud

I am sharing iCloud storage with a person and want to remove them because the capacity is almost at max. I don't think it will happen but I want to make sure I don't mess up: will they lose any pictures or files? They are using 80GB of space right now, which is not covered by the free subscription (50GB). I guess they will be asked to book a bigger package until they can access their data again? Thanks for any clarification on this.

Comment: It would seem to me from reading https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201081#stopsharing that they will immediately lose all access to that storage  - but I can't actually confirm for certain.

Comment: No, that's shared photo albums, etc. I am talking about their personal files.

Comment: "won't have access to any services shared by your family, such as an Apple Music family subscription or a **shared iCloud storage plan**."

Comment: Yes, they will clearly lose access to the iCloud storage (that's the point of deleting them), but what happens to their personal files? We are using the same space, but each of us has distinct files which are not shared.

Comment: As I already said… they will lose access. Now whether that means Apple will offer them to pay for their own space I don't know, but I doubt it, otherwise it would be mentioned. So, they need to offload that data first, or lose it. There may be another interpretation, but if there is, I'm not seeing it anywhere.

Comment: Whatever the interpretation of Apple's rules, it would be prudent (to say the least) to make sure that you both have a backup of your files from iCloud storage before changing anything.

Comment: It sounds quite inconvenient that anything will be lost. iCloud _is_ the backup by definition, right? It comprises photos, calendar, notes, whatsapp backups etc. etc. How am I backing up my backup solution?

Comment: iCloud is not a backup solution, it is a synchronisation solution. It does store iDevice backups, but not independent data backups. That's not its job.